# Lightning page is blank after installing the package in prod

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, lightning-experience, beta-managed-package

Below is the simple hello lightning page..

1. Create a Custom Button on Opportunity with following formula.

   `/apex/namespace__testHelloVFpage`

   Name This button testHello. Drag and drop this button in Opportunity pagelayout to use it.
2. Create a Visual force page using below code and Name it as testHelloVFpage

   ```
   <apex:page sidebar="true" showHeader="true" standardController="Opportunity"> 
       <apex:includeLightning /> 
       <center><div id="lightning" style="margin-left:1%;max-width:75%;margin-bottom:2%;"/>
       </center> 
       <script > 
       $Lightning.use("namespace:testHelloEsignPageApp", function() { 
           $Lightning.createComponent("namespace:testHelloEsignLC", {}, 
               "lightning", 
               function(component) {
                    window.$Force = sforce;
               }); 
        }); 
       </script> 
   </apex:page>
   ```
3. Create a Lightning app using below code and name it as `testHelloEsignPageApp`

   ```
   <aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
        <aura:dependency resource="namespace:testHelloEsignLC"/> 
   </aura:application>
   ```
4. Create Lightning component bundle using below component code and name it testHelloEsignLC

   ```
   <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" > 
         ########### This is a Test Component ############### <br></br> 
         *********** Hello ESign ************* 
   </aura:component>
   ```
5. Now once we click on custom button that we have created in step one, it will show us this Lightning page. No issues

---

NOTE :- nameSpace in above code is domain name.

I have created a simple beta package and installed it another dev org/ managed on production..

I am simply getting blank page. Nothing else. Can anyone tell me what and where I'm doing mistake.

Comment: Please use the `{}` tool, along with appropriate tabbing and braces, to format your code. It makes the community's job harder if we can't read your work. I've fixed it here.

Comment: I apologise for that not using those tools. I'm using Android app to post it.  Above code looks absolutely correct to me too. But from my org, it's just showing blank screen on once I install the package and try to use it. Please let me know if you have ever faced this issue anytime before.

Comment: I would imagine yes, but still asking - does the User accessing the button/page have access to the VF page? Also I will assume that the target org is lightning/my domain enabled?

Comment: Yes @jayantDas, target org is domain enabled and I am accessing button/page as system admin. I am able to access all other normal Visualforce pages without any issues, I should've mentioned this.

Comment: Does the javascript console show any relevant errors?

Comment: No errors in console.log.. but i see "Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided does not match the recipient window’s origin " in inspect element. It's not any console.log... this message with other bunch of errors like typeError which I see in some normal loading pages also..

Comment: Have you ever solved it?

Comment: No I did not yet. As a workaround, I used var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent"); event and fired by passing params. This bypassed VF page. Even I had to use iFrame so I used normal APEX classic VF page instead of lightning because of this issue.